# Can we resize an ImageField from inside a validation function in Django?

Tags: python, django, validation, django-models

Is it legal to modify data from inside a validation function in Django? I need to autoresize images from `ImageFields`.

In the docs it says that these kind of functions should raise `ValidationError`, but instead I need to actually modify the data (`image` in this case). I'd like to do it like this because I have to apply this to several models. If I could do this, I wouldn't need to change the forms in the admin.

```
def image_field_autoresize(image):
    if image.width > MAX_IMAGE_WIDTH:
        raise ValidationError(u'image width error')
    if image.height > MAX_IMAGE_HEIGHT:
        raise ValidationError(u'image height error')
```

Comment: Looks like to independent things to me. First, I would do resize on the models save function, secondly you can validate that the uploaded image does not exceed your set sizes which belongs to the form/model validation for my understandings.

Comment: I didn't want to modify the image dimensions inside `save`, as this isn't the best place for validation. I've just accepted @karthikr's answer, you can see the discussion there to better understand what I needed and how I'll solve it. Regards!

Comment: Hi @Jingo! After some testing, I realised that from inside a `clean` method we can't use the `ImageField` content to read it using PIL. So, I think that the best place to do the resizing is the `save()` method, as you suggested at the begining. As I need this process to be user-transparent, I don't need to implement any form validation. Thanks! (I've upvoted your comment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a discussion with @karthikr, I can conclude with the following:

If you need to change data in a validation process, you can override `clean_<fieldname>()` from the `ModelForm` class. In your `clean()` method in `ModelForm` you shouldn't do that. And if you need to do some image resizing I found that the best place is Model's `save()` method.

I've solved the problem like this:

I've created a new module named `image.py` that contains a function that takes as parameter the image's absolute path, implements the resizing logic and modifies the image size. In my case, the "resizing logic" reduces the image proportionally if the width is bigger that a given size.

```
from PIL import Image
from django.conf import settings


def autoresize_image(image_path):
    image = Image.open(image_path)
    width = image.size[0]
    if width > settings.IMAGE_MAX_WIDTH:
        height = image.size[1]
        reduce_factor = settings.IMAGE_MAX_WIDTH / float(width)
        reduced_width = int(width * reduce_factor)
        reduced_height = int(height * reduce_factor)
        image = image.resize((reduced_width, reduced_height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        image.save(image_path)
```

I call this function from `save()` method in the Model that contains an `ImageField` to be resized. Points to keep in mind here: call `super()` before trying to resize the image or it won't be found as it won't be already saved in your hdd and if the `ImageField` is not required, check if value is given. It looks like:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Startup, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    if self.logo:
        autoresize_image(self.logo.path)
```

Thanks to @Jingo as well for his comment. It's been very useful :)